# Открытие нового окна браузера

Tags: visual-basic, vb.net, vba

Как сделать, чтобы браузер, построенный в Visual Basic 2010, не запускал IE для просмотра новой страницы, а открывал страницу в этом же браузере (то есть браузер без вкладок и новых окон)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно перехватывать событие WebBrowser.NewWindow и в нем самостоятельно создавать новое окно WebBrowser. А если окажется, что в у VB Webbrowser ограниченный функционал, тогда можно использовать напрямую COM-объект из shdocvw.dll.

Comment: Там достаточный функционал.